# How do you find the inscribed rectangles in an arbitrary Jordan curve?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, rectangles

In this video, a proof is presented that there always exists at least one inscribed rectangle in any enclosed curve. Is there an algorithmic method for finding the coordinates of the inscribed rectangles for an arbitrary curve?

There are many articles about that prove such a rectangle must exist, but I have found no methods for actually finding those rectangles.

[Who cares about topology? (Inscribed rectangle problem)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the curve is given implicitly by $F(x) = 0$.  The vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ of your rectangle are then solutions of the system

$$ \eqalign{F(v_1) &= 0 \cr
            F(v_2) &= 0 \cr
            F(v_3) &= 0 \cr
            F(v_4) &= 0 \cr
            (v_1 - v_2) \cdot (v_2 - v_3) &= 0\cr
            (v_2 - v_3) \cdot (v_3 - v_4) &= 0\cr
            (v_3 - v_4) \cdot (v_4 - v_1) &= 0\cr
            (v_4 - v_1) \cdot (v_1 - v_2) &= 0\cr} $$

We can try solving this system, numerically or symbolically (maybe using Groebner bases if $F$ is a polynomial), avoiding the trivial solutions  $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = v_4$.  Hopefully there will be only finitely many such solutions, and some of them give your inscribed rectangles.

EDIT: For an example such as yours (produced using splines), an implicit equation isn't going to be easy to find.  However, a parametric equation can be obtained.  If the curve is given parametrically as $x = X(t)$, $0 \le t \le L$, and the vertices are $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, $X(t_3)$, $X(t_4)$, then the equations are

$$ \eqalign{(X(t_1) - X(t_2)) \cdot (X(t_2) - X(t_3)) &= 0\cr
 (X(t_2) - X(t_3)) \cdot (X(t_3) - X(t_4)) &= 0\cr
 (X(t_3) - X(t_4)) \cdot (X(t_4) - X(t_1)) &= 0\cr
 (X(t_4) - X(t_1)) \cdot (X(t_1) - X(t_2)) &= 0\cr}$$

Comment: And, of course, the corresponding problem for a square is notoriously unsolved.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I want your help to be more concrete before I give it the check mark.

Suppose I have an arbitrary spline, such as the following example (https://i.imgur.com/mG0agHQ.png) I've just drawn (I can provide the .SVG). To use your method we must first find the equation that describes this curve. So help me proceed with an example (it doesn't have to be that curve specifically).